# How to define keyword/variadic arguments in a NotImplementedYet ABC method (avoiding pylint: arguments-differ)

Tags: python, overriding, abstract-class, pylint

I have an Abstract Base Class in python that looks like this:

```py
from abc import abstractmethod

class Task:
    @abstractmethod
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

This is provided to the users of my library who will inherit from it with their own options:

```py
class UserTask(Task):
    def run(self, price=1, quantity=1, discount=0.5):
        return price * quantity * (1 - discount)
```

In the `UserTask` I get the following two pylint warnings:

- `Number of parameters was 2 in 'Task.run' and is now 4 in overridden 'UserTask.run' method: pylint(arguments-differ)`
- `Variadics removed in overridden 'UserTask.run' method: pylint(arguments-differ)`

I have also tried overriding with additional `**kwargs` to make sure the signature is fully compliant:

```py
class UserTask(Task):
    def run(self, price=1, quantity=1, discount=0.5, **kwargs):
        return price * quantity * (1 - discount)
```

That removes the `Variadics removed` warning (which is a legitimate warning) but the `Number of parameters` warning remains.

#### The question

Are these pylint messages overly cautious? It feels like pylint doesn't understand the `**` operator... but the warnings will appear in my users' code, not in mine, and I'd rather they don't have to customise their pylint config to use my library!

How should I encourage my users to override the `run` method, and/or how should I alter its signature, to enable users to override it without getting this warning?

#### Background for interest

This is popping up whilst building the Cloud Tasks manager for [django-gcp](https://django-gcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Do the warnings still show if you use `def run(self, price=1, quantity=1, discount=0.5, **kwargs)` or `def run(self, **kwargs)` in the `UserTask` class? I couldn't reproduce the second pylint warning with these two signatures.

Comment: edited to explain more clearly what happens, thank you @mahieyin-rahmun

Comment: Consider a list of containing values of various subclasses of `Task`. If that's all you know about the list, you should expect that each object's `run` method can take the same arguments, because `Task.run` places no restrictions on what arguments can be passed. `UserTask` violates that by placing new restrictions on what can and can't be passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Liskov Substitution Principle requires that an instance of `UserTask` be usable anywhere an instance of `Task` is expected. Restricting the arguments `UserTask.run` can accept violates the LSP.

Make `Task` *generic* in the type of argument it can accept.

```
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')

class Task(Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def run(self, config: T):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class UserConfig:
    ...


class UserTask(Task[UserConfig]):
    def run(self, config: UserConfig):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a `Config` class that can be subclassed by your users, and which holds the contents you would normally pass through the `**kwargs`:

```py
from abc import abstractmethod

class Config:
    ...


class Task:
    @abstractmethod
    def run(self, config: Config) -> None:
        ...


class UserConfig(Config):
    ...


class UserTask(Task):
    def run(self, config: UserConfig) -> None:
        ...
```

Comment: This still violates the Liskov Substitution Principle.